# The Difficulty of finding the object properties (reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers But I have a problem with the method is Deserialize

I want the tab grid (Customer Grid ) when I click on any row in order to be seen for a specific customer.

But I think the main problem is in this line, this line is Deseriailize method.

```
var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Because the code does not get the object properties properly

[**Project Files**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy6rp1rghyqjrs8/CoustomersApp.rar)

[**Please see the video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tN-wH_VtPCI&feature=youtu.be)

```
 public T Deserialize<T>(string entity)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var stringProps = entity.Split(',');
        var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        var propIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringProps.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
                }
                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(stringProps[i]), null);
                }
                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
                {
                    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
                    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stringProps[i], cultureInfo);
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, dateTime, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
                propIndex++;
            }

            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Index Out Of range");
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: What are you passing as `string entity` when calling this method?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not get the object properties properly"? Does it return nothing? Are you sure they are properties, not fields?

Comment: public virtual List<T> OrderFindById(int id)
        {
            var allLines = FRepository.LoadAll();

            foreach (var line in allLines)
            {
                if (line.EndsWith(id + ","))
                {
                    var objOrder = Serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(line);
                    return objOrder;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

Comment: _"Please see the video"_ - nope, please explain your problem by writing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `Serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(line)` hence `GetProperties()` returns properties of `List<T>`, not `T` itself. They are:

- `Int32 Capacity`
- `Int32 Count`
- `OrderItem Int32`

so what is your code trying to execute is to assign `stringProps[i]` with value `30/1/2008` to `Int32 Count` property.